# How to add / import / install Gesture in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, gesture

I try to create [sliding segments](https://medium.com/@siddhartha.ng/ionic3-swipeable-segments-70943cafa5fd) using this example. This example in ionic 3 and I want to make it work for **ionic 4** and in this example, he is using Gesture. But the problem is I am not able to import Gesture.

in example imported this Ionic v3:

```
import { Gesture } from 'ionic-angular/gestures/gesture';
```

so as we importing other `@ionic/angular` but showing error:

```
import { Gesture } from '@ionic/angular/gestures/gesture';
```

> Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular/gestures/gesture'.ts(2307)

In short, I just want to import gestures in my **ionic 4 projects**. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The Ionic team is working on adding gesture support to Ionic v4 right now. See this [issue in on Github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19183) and especially [this comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19183#issuecomment-524851087).

Ionic is moving from HammerJS-based gestures towards a custom solution, so I'd either subscribe to the issue above and wait for the feature to be completed or you can install and use [HammerJS](https://hammerjs.github.io/).

Latter is described in detail [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0). First, you need to install HammerJS via npm:

```
npm install hammerjs
```

Then you'll have to add the following import to your `main.ts`:

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Then you should be able to use gesture bindings, as you're used to, e.g.:

```
<div (swipe)="onSwipe($event)"></div>
```

The blog post mentioned above offers some more examples and also a [list of available events](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5298b2bda34a8766b28c8425e447f94598b23901/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/events/hammer_gestures.ts#L15).